# onChange on dynamically created elements

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I created dynamically 2 elements. Now I would like copy data from richTextBox to WebBrowser on event onChange

How can I copy data from richTextBox to WebBrowser when I created it dynamically?

My code

```
void OpenFile(string path, string filename)
{
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(path);

    if(richTextBox1.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        TabPage tp = new TabPage();
        int tc = tabControl1.TabCount + 1;
        tp.Text = filename;
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);

        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        rtb.Width = tp.Width / 2;
        rtb.Height = tp.Height;
        rtb.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(setText);
        rtb.Text = read.ReadToEnd();

        wb.Left = tp.Width / 2;
        wb.Width = tp.Width / 2;
        wb.Height = tp.Height;

        tp.Controls.Add(rtb);
        tp.Controls.Add(wb);

        return;
    }
}

private void setText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("TEXT CHANGED");
}
```

Comment: I havn't idea how can i do it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
rtb.TextChanged += (s, e) => { wb.DocumentText = rtb.Text; };
```